# Unity URP to WebGL is ignoring Sampler State

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, shader-graph, urp

The Sampler State is being ignored once exported to WebGL. I have a plane that has one of its faces setup as to over extend the UV's 0-1 space, so the effect would make the texture applyied to it look smaller... it looks ok in the editor, but once exported as webgl, the clamping stops working and the texture gets repeated... is this a limitation of WebGL or a bug?

[How it looks in the Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzjH8.jpg)

[How it looks once exported as WebGL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZtl2.jpg)

[UV layout of UV4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAPEF.jpg)

[Shader Graph Node Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNzWR.jpg)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please post your solution as an answer, and mark it as correct, instead of including it directly inside the question. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION: well i had the image used as decal with wrap mode set to repeat. I set it to clamp and it worked. Idk why the Sampler Node doesn't override this setting... i was especting the image to use whatever wrap method the sampler node was set to use. And weird enough... if the image uses repeat but the sampler node sets clamp, it wont work, final sampling will use repeat. But if you set the image to clamp and the sampler node is set to repeat, the image will be repeated... weird...